# Issue with Visual Studios Data Type alteration

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sqltools

I have gathered a data set from sql to use in visual studios, some of which are large numbers and others which are small. I want any value below 100 to show 1 decimal place and anything above to show as an integer without any decimal places.

When I am using CINT() or Round( ,0) the number still shows with a .0 as the end due to the data type of the cell. Can anyone think of a way around this?

Comment: Which is your frontend?

Comment: I'm using sql server data tools